# QT Creator on Win 10, "Failed to retrieve MSVC Environment"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, qt-creator, qt5.6

QT's full error, which takes over a minute to appear while the GUI is unresponsive:

`:-1: error: Failed to retrieve MSVC Environment from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64":
 The command "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" could not be started.`

My QT project compiles fine on the Windows 7, with QT 5.6 (compiler MSVC2015 64-bit), QT creator 4.4.0 and Visual Studio Professional 2015. But I get this error, on Windows 10, when I attempt to run QT 5.6 (same compiler), QT Creator 4.4.1 and Visual Studio Express 2015. The error message seems to be nonsensical, how can QT not find cmd.exe?

It's clear that QT's missing something from either Windows 10 or VS, which it can't get before timing out.

--**EDIT2**--

Some progress: Part of the issue must've been the Express Edition. At least MSVS2017 Express doesn't come with a 64 bit compiler.

Wiping QT5.6/VS'15 and trying the latest versions (MSVS2017 **Community** Edition and QT 5.9), I can compile from QtCreator. BUT, only if I open QT's command prompt, run the vcvarsall.bat file for a 64 bit environment and then qtcreator from that prompt. ie:

```
"\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary"\Build\vcvarsall.bat amd64
qtcreator
```

So the question is really why QT isn't pick up the VS environment variables? I've tried searching online but the sole post that I found online, asking how QtCreator is initialised.. remains unanswered.

--**EDIT1**--

Neglected to include, I've been (trying to) install:

- Visual Studio Express 2015 for Desktop
- (tried Express 2015 for Windows 10 briefly before realising my mistake and swiftly uninstalled!)
- Windows SDK 10.0.10586.212
- QT 5.6 (with MSVC2015 compiler) and bundled QT Creator (4.4.1) with its debugger

Also, the PC was wiped and installed with a clean image recently. That was a couple of weeks ago so there really isn't much junk on it (save for me trying to install VS and QT..?).

---

### The gritty details

Searching for this specific error, there are 2 recent bugs submitted to QT.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-19099

Examining the suggestions there: cmd.exe starts in 10 seconds on Windows 10, compared to 3 seconds on Windows 7 - Can't conceivably be an issue here?

My PATH environment variable contains only absolute paths.

I looked through the registry but couldn't find the location of the AutoRun key for Command Processor. The registry path specified differ from what I see in my machine?

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-18886

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I just can't see how to debug this any further.

Comment: Not a solution as I've not (yet) fully solved this. However, the time it takes to load the vsvarsall.bat file should be <=5 seconds. Mine's taking 9s on a pretty new Win 10 machine. Whereas it takes 3s on a 5years+ Win 7 machine, which doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Some debugging suggestions should anyone else stumble across this issue: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-19099

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments above helped to find the likely source. I couldn't "fix" it, but get around it by opening the Qt developer's cmd prompt, load the appropriate vsvarsall.bat file and the run qtcreator from the same cmd prompt. QtCreator will subsequently be unresponsive for over a minute after it's started, but then it'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using clink?

I removed it, and now I don't have that problem.

Comment: Could you please expand on your suggestion? (I can make an educated guess what clink is - linking within QT creator? Although searching the web, I find nothing obvious - there are 2 GitHub projects of the same name, for instance.). Apologies, not having a terribly productive day here...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. For me, the culprit was an application I installed that runs before each launch of cmd.exe which was delaying it's launch time hence causing the issue. Removing that application fixed it for me.